# How to get Google Cloud Shell within Firefox ESR 52.5.0 on CentOS6 to work reliably?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, firefox, google-cloud-shell

In a single browser window, Google Cloud Shell only lets me have one instance that is not corrupt.  Screenshots explain.  Is there something one can do using  **Firefox 57 Quantum on Windows 10** or Firefox ESR 52.5.0 on CentOS6 to have multiple google cloud shells that are actually useable?  Resizing text in one "tab" may fix corruption in that tab at the cost of corrrupting the other tab.
[image]

Comment: It sounds like this is a browser specific issue- you can report it to Mozilla [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/new). Does this issue persist when you select the "Open in new window"  option within the Cloud Shell to detach the Cloud Shell(s) from the main Console?

Comment: Yes, the screenshot is from a window dedicated to just google-cloud shell.  Also happens on Windows 10 Firefox 57.  Used your link to report and also the "Send Feedback" from within the cloud shell triple dot menu.

Comment: `clear` removes the line overlays but executing a series of commands is still unreadable.

Comment: This has been reported and logged on Google's issue tracker. You can track the issue here [https://issuetracker.google.com/69904646](https://issuetracker.google.com/69904646)

Answer (score 0):

You can try running Cloud Shell in safe mode by appending `cloudshellsafemode=true` to the URL.

Sometimes running browsers in **incognito mode** helps prevent some browser extensions to cause unintended behavior.

https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features#safe_mode